# How to modularize module in make menuconfig

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, make

In the `make menuconfig` interface, I would like to modularize a module. I can set the module with a star (*). It's meaning the module will be compiled in core. 
I'm not able to set it with a M . I'm pressing on the M touch nothing happen.

**Update**

The target is to set available the DisplayLink module like this procedure : http://goo.gl/PQn362

Take care there are differences between the command applied in  the video, the blog and my own  interface of menuconfig I got with my raspberry PI (should be the version of the last one). 
In the video of the `make menuconfig`  interface (at 4m:47s) the guy is setting the "DispalyLink USB framebuffer support" as modularize with M. I can not do the same. I can put a star (*) only.

However, the command in video  `make -j4 zImage modules dtbs` doesn't work. The same command whithout the `-j4` option works like in the blog. 
I've got this error message which is stopping the compilation :

```
CALL scripts/checksycalls.sh
CHK include/generated/compil.h
Kernel: arch/arm/boot/Image is ready
Kernel; arch/arm/boot/zImage is ready

The present Kernel configuration has modules disabled.
Type 'make config' and enable loadable module support.
Then build a kernel with module support enabled.

Makefile:1283 : the reciept of the taget modules failed
make: *** [modules] Erreur 1
```

I did make config but I understanding nothing about the question asked
I edited the file `.config` I didn't find any issue.

Comment: what is `the M touch` that you are `pressing on`? and `a module` ... hwich one?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: What module is it? Some can only be built-in to the kernel as they won't run as loadable modules.

Comment: I put an update with more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a top level choice in the main menu of `menuconfig`:

```
[ ] Enable loadable module support
```

You want to select that, then there is a submenu; the defaults there are probably fine particularly if you are just building a module and not the whole kernel.

Be warned though, if the source version you are using doesn't match the kernel you want to load this into, it won't work.

Comment: `make -j4 zImage modules dtbs` worked until the end without error but the dtbs files have not been created.